# Kubernetes Load balancer - External-ip always pending

Tags: kubernetes

I have Kubernetes 1.26 with containerd ona ubuntu VM, 1 control plaine and 2 nodes (ubuntu also). I did a deployment and a service with loadbalancer.
When I run
Kubectl get services
the loadbalancer External-IP always in "Pending" status.
I issued
kubectl describle service myservice

I get the follwoing which seems, if I am not mistaken that there are no errors.

[image]

So the question is how can troubleshoot/debug and uncover the reason behind this? Knowing that I have applied another deployment with same type of service and it was working fine which I delete before applying the 2nd deployment and service.

Here is the deployment yml and the service yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: stable-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: aspnetcore
      track: stable
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: aspnetcore
        track: stable
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: stable-app
        image: stable-app
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 80
        resources: {}


kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: stable-service
  labels:
    app: aspnetcore
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: aspnetcore
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't have enough information to tell exactly what's wrong. However, you are saying you run your own control plane, so you are probably not running on a cloud provider with a Cloud Controller Manager installed.
Kubernetes does not actually know how to create a LoadBalancer service itself, since it is a bit reliant on the cloud provider you're running on. I suggest looking into something like MetalLB or k3s' Klipper for that. Another solution is an ingress controller with HostPort

Comment: Also, technically (I just figured this out myself just now) the Kubernetes tag on StackOverflow is only meant for programming questions. I think the appropriate website for this sort of question is ServerFault.

Comment: OK thanks, yes it is on-prem setup and as I said, I have another deployment and service applied yesterday which worked fine